# Did Elvis fake his own death?

Tags: history, celebrities

He'd be quite old now so even if he did fake his death, he's probably dead anyway, but over the years, there's been many Elvis sightings. Have there been any actual credible ones?

Comment: There hasn't been any actual Elvis sightings since Elvis left this planet to go home. [Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/quotes?qt=qt1313798)

Comment: No, but he did fake the JFK assassination

Comment: Strangely enough, I've known a lot of Elvis *Impersonators* in my life. Many could probably convince me in and of themselves that they were Elvis if I didn't know any better.  Sorry I just think that way too many people out there have fallen victims to some damn good impersonators.

Comment: I think SMBC answered this:  http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20110509after.gif  hehe

Answer (score 11):

[image: Humour]

There are no credible sightings for Elvis.  In actuality, a real Elvis sightinig ranks up there with the Ivory Billed Woodpecker, Bigfoot, or Chupecabra.

[This website has Elvis's death certificate, autopsy report, and exhumation examination posted on it](http://www.elvispresleynews.com/ElvisDeathCertificate.html).  There was some controversy about the cause of death, and the final attribution.  One of Elvis's doctors was under investigation for malpractice (and considering the prescriptions in Elvis's possession, with good cause).

[image: Death Certificate]

[image: Elvis Exhumed]

[The Committee for Skeptical Inquiry also did a write up and study](http://www.csicop.org/sb/show/theres_no_debate_elvis_is_not_alive/).

> There are no facts to support the theory that Elvis faked his death, and the debate itself is not valid. It is time to set the record straight and properly frame the issue because this faulty debate has gone on far too long. Many Elvis fans are tired of it, the tabloids seem to have become tired of it, and certainly the Presley family has heard enough about it.

The article concludes with an interesting bit (emphasis mine):

> Several years ago, another construct of the alive vs. dead debate was presented to me in the form of a question: *“Can you prove beyond a reasonable doubt that Elvis Presley died on August 16, 1977?” How did the burden of proof get shifted to the side where all the direct and circumstantial evidence supports the fact that Elvis Presley did in fact die on August 16, 1977?* By asking this question, the Alivers are attempting to prop up the debate as if they bear no burden to prove their claims. They are insinuating that if I cannot absolutely prove that Elvis Presley died, he must have faked his death. It’s a nice trick, but it doesn’t work. The burden of proof, by legal standards, lies with the person who makes the charge. When a person charges that Elvis Presley faked his death—a claim that defies all wisdom, logic, and documented information—the burden to prove that charge falls squarely on that person’s shoulders.
>
> Furthermore, the person making the charge must not only establish positive evidence of his claim but must also negate the oppositional evidence. Have the Alivers negated the statements of eyewitnesses who saw Elvis’s body after he was pronounced dead at 3:30 pm that day? No, they have not. Have they negated the voluminous body of documentation pertaining to the death? No, they have not. Have they negated the statements, many taken under oath, from the physicians who conducted the autopsy on Elvis’s body? No, they have not.
>
> If there are two opposing sides and one side has no facts and no evidence, can there be a valid debate? The answer is no, which is why the idea that Elvis faked his death should be erased from our collective consciousness. The debate itself is not valid.

Either that, or you can take Skava's comment as the answer.  :)

[image: Evil Elvis Lives]

Comment: No fair dad!  You stole my joke!

Comment: I didn't steal it, I gave you credit!

Comment: I couldn't find the an authoratative source from famous quote attributed to one of the doctors at the autopsy: "If he wasn't dead before the autopsy, he certainly was afterwards."  I did find [this written about Dr. Jerry Francisco](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1988-08-16/features/8801230242_1_autopsy-fat-elvis-medical-examiner), one of the doctors present for the autopsy. "In his roles as a pathology instructor and as medical examiner for Shelby County and the State of Tennessee, Francisco estimates he has seen 30,000 to 40,000 dead people in his life.

Elvis, he says, fit the profile."

Comment: It's "chupacabra" not "chupecabras", chupa-cabra means goat sucker, while chupe-cabra can be translated as "I sucked a goat"